# Losing some samples while writing to file in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, sampling

I'm continuosly getting readings from an ADC in Python, but during the process of writing it to a file, I lose some samples because there is some small delay. Is there a way I could avoid losing these samples (I'm sampling at 100Hz)?

I'm using multithreading, but in the process of writing and cleaning the list used to write the data to a file, I always lose some samples. The code is copied here as I have written it and all advice is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

```
import threading
import time
from random import randint
import os
from datetime import datetime
import ADS1256
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import sys
import os
import csv

ADC=ADS1256.ADS1256()
ADC.ADS1256_init()


value_list=[]

#adc_reading function reads adc values and writes a list continuously.

def adc_reading():
    
    global value_list
    value_list=[]
    while True:
        
        
        
        
        adc_value=ADC.ADS1256_GetAll()
        timestamp=time.time()
        x=adc_value[1]
        y=adc_value[2]
        z=adc_value[3]
        value_list.append([timestamp,x,y,z])
            
        
#function to create a new file every 60 seconds with the values gathered in adc_reading()

def cronometro():
    global value_list
    
    
    
    
    while True:
        
        contador=60
        inicio=time.time()
        diferencia=0
        
        while diferencia<=contador:
            diferencia=time.time()-inicio

            
        write_to_file(value_list)
        
#write_to_file() function writes the values gathered in adc_reading() to a file every 60 seconds.

def write_to_file(lista):
    
    
    nombre_archivo=str(int(time.time()))+".finish"
    with open(nombre_archivo, 'w') as f:
      
            # using csv.writer method from CSV package
        write = csv.writer(f)
            
            
        write.writerows(lista)
        value_list=[]

escritor = threading.Thread(target=adc_reading)
temporizador = threading.Thread(target=cronometro)
escritor.start()
temporizador.start()
```

Comment: The two threads won't run in parallel, they will alternate. You could run the data collection in a separate process and collect data from that from the main process (using `multiprocessing` instead of threads). However, at a 100Hz, I have to wonder if the write operation really takes longer than 10ms. You could probably do both operations in the same loop and just collect data in a buffer and write it once every 60 seconds without incurring more than a few milliseconds delay.

Answer (score 1):

At a 100Hz, I have to wonder if the write operation really takes longer than 10ms. You could probably do both operations in the same loop and just collect data in a buffer and write it (about 6000 values) once every 60 seconds without incurring more than a few milliseconds delay:

```
import time
import ADS1256
import csv


ADC = ADS1256.ADS1256()
ADC.ADS1256_init()


def adc_reading():
    buffer = []
    contador = 60
    while True:
        check = inicio = time.time()
        while check - inicio <= contador:
            adc_value = ADC.ADS1256_GetAll()
            buffer.append([(check := time.time()), *adc_value[1:4]])
        
        nombre_archivo = str(int(check)) + ".finish"
        with open(nombre_archivo, 'w') as f:
            write = csv.writer(f)
            write.writerows(buffer)
            buffer = []


if __name__ == '__main__':
    adc_reading()
```

If you do need them to run in parallel (slow computer, other circumstances), you shouldn't use threads, but processes from `multiprocessing`.

The two threads won't run in parallel, they will alternate. You could run the data collection in a separate process and collect data from that from the main process.

Here's an example of doing this with some toy code, I think it's easy to see how to adjust for your case:

```
from multiprocessing import SimpleQueue, Process
from random import randint
from time import sleep, time


def generate_signals(q: SimpleQueue):
    c = 0
    while True:
        sleep(0.01)  # about 100 Hz
        q.put((c, randint(1, 42)))
        c += 1


def write_signals(q: SimpleQueue):
    delay = 3  # 3 seconds for demo, 60 works as well
    while True:
        start = time()
        while (check := time()) - start < delay:
            sleep(.1)
        values = []
        while not q.empty():
            values.append(str(q.get()))
        with open(f'{str(int(check))}.finish', 'w') as f:
            f.write('\n'.join(values))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = SimpleQueue()
    generator = Process(target=generate_signals, args=((q),))
    generator.start()

    writer = Process(target=write_signals, args=((q),))
    writer.start()

    writer.join(timeout=10)  # run for no more than 10 seconds, enough for demo
    writer.kill()
    generator.join(timeout=0)
    generator.kill()
```

Edit: added a counter, to show that no values are missed.

Comment: Still losing some samples while writing the file. In the link you can see the gap in the data, but thanks for the answer!  [link] https://ibb.co/tDNTGKz

Comment: I've added a solution with `multiprocessing` - that shouldn't lose any. It's just a toy example, but that's because I don't have access to your environment and I wanted to post something I could actually test.

Comment: Updated with a counter to show it's not losing any.